# Got an error while setup Scandipwa on magento 2.3.5

Tags: localhost, magento2, progressive-web-apps, magento-2.3

while installing scandipwa i got an error after enter the command

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:config:set --pq-host localhost
```

The "--pq-host" option does not exist.
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please use specific version  **composer require scandipwa/installer": "^2.0**